# Printer output shifted on a Brother DCP-135C

Tags: printing

Whenever I print anything, the output is shifted about 3 cm towards the top. That causes the 3-4 first lines to be "cut off" and it will start printing the ~ 4th line. (And of course therefore the page is blank within the last lines.)

I print using Evince. Oh, btw, printing with Adobe Reader won't print at all. (With no visible error message in the GUI.)

Any idea how to fix that? I have a Brother DCP-135C and the newest stable Ubuntu version..

Comment: The answer also applies to `Brother DCP-330C` on Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at file `/usr/local/Brother/Printer/**your model**/inf/br**your model**rc` (probably `/usr/local/Brother/Printer/dcp135c/inf/brdcp135crc`) and verify if the value of `PaperType` matches your paper size.

That happened to me when settings were "Letter" and my paper was "A4".

Answer (score 2):

The [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/79654/65926) Salem provided helped me too but in my case the file was located in the folder:

```
/usr/Brother/Printer/dcp135c/inf/
```

not

```
/usr/local/Brother/Printer/dcp135c/inf/
```

Comment: This answer would be more useful if you were to [edit] it to include the version of Ubuntu you were running when you located the file. Thank you!

Comment: I'm sry but I don't remember which version of ubuntu i was using 5 years ago.

Comment: No worries, I didn't expect that you did. Just a tip for future reference. :-)